# Is there any Post request functionality using Ember store in Route?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I was wondering if there is any ember store functionality like this.store.findAll('report') which is actually a GET request but for POST of postObj in my route and how can i deal with the response I get back. Currently i'm sending ajax POST request.

Comment: `model.save()` is how to trigger a POST or PUT for a particular record.

Comment: @Grapho is correct. To handle the result, implement a function that goes to the `then` handler:
    
    model.save().then(function(response){
    // play around with your result
    }).catch(function(error){
    // analyse error, inform user, whatever
    });

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
store.findAll('report', { adapterOptions: { method: 'POST' } })
```

But you have to override [`findAll`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_findAll) in your adapter and make the ajax request yourself. You can check what method by getting the `adapterOptions` from the snapshot array.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

const { get } = Ember;

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  findAll(store, type, sinceToken, snapshotRecordArray) {
    let method = get(snapshotRecordArray, 'adapterOptions.method');
    let url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, snapshotRecordArray, 'findAll');
    // ...
    // return promise
  }
});
```

**Note, it is not recommended to use put or post for fetching records and is a code smell most likely.**

Comment: Because you are looking to change the find behavior, not the save behavior. If that is not the case, please fix your question.

Comment: Thanks for you solution, for now I decided to go with sending regular Ajax post requests due to my code requirements.